# String to Json convert issues

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a Json which is converted to string and then writted in DataBase

```
function UpdateFilter() {

    var filterOption = {
        "filterTarget": "Books",
        "filters": [
            { "cancelled": $("#showCancelledFilter").is(':checked') },
            { "completed": $("#showAllFilter").is(':checked') }
        ],
        "page": page,
        "sorting": sorting
    };

    var url = "Library/Books/UpdateFilter";
    $.post(url, { pageFilters: JSON.stringify(filterOption) }, function (data) { });
}
```

Up until this point everything seems to be fine.

Issue starts when I am trying to get json from string:

```
var data = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Seems fine **BUT** in:

```
$.get('Library/Books/GetPageFilters', null, function(data) {
    filterOption = data;
}, "json");
```

I have received a object with 4 arrays (each on each json property, and each array has empty array inside it).

I assume that I am lacking something in converting string to json, but I can't get it.

What am I missing?

Comment: The values of the `page` and `sorting` properties should be enclosed in double quotes if they are string values.

Comment: those are `var page` and `var sorting`.

Comment: how does the GetPageFilters method look like?

Answer (score 0):

I gess your problem situated where you using `$.get()` jquery method. From [documentation of $.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

> dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server.
>   **Default: Intelligent Guess** (xml, json, script, or html).

Seem like Intelligent Guess can't understand what was come from server.

Try [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) insted.